# How to connect GraphEdit to my app's graph

Tags: c++, directshow

I am trying to figure out how to get GraphEdit to show me my running graph from my app.  I running windows 7 64bit.

In the directshow sdk samples they have a spot for registering with the rot.  I read on M$'s site that I needed to register the droppage.dll(cant recall the exact name right now).  So I did that, but still no dice.

Any idea's?

Answer (score 1):

Remember that on a 64-bit machine, you will need to use the 64-bit graphedt and 64-bit proppage.dll for your 64-bit app (and 32-bit graphedt/proppage for a 32-bit app). And if you are in admin mode with VS, you will need to be in admin mode for graphedt.

Comment: I don't see two version of the graph edit program in the sdk's bin directory.  Is it safe to assume that it is a 32 bit version?

Comment: in Program Files/Microsoft SDKs/Windows/v6.1/Bin you will find the 32-bit versions. Under that, there is a subdirectory "x64" containing the 64-bit versions.